# After upgrading Zend Server CE from 5.0.3 to 5.0.4 xdebug stopped working

Tags: zend-server

Hello I updated today Zend Server CE from 5.0.3 to 5.0.4 on my Windows xp machine.

But since the upgrade i got the following error:

```
Failed loading K:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.2-vc6-nts.dll
Failed loading K:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\dbg-php-5.2.dll
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Same here. Can't configure xdebug with zend server CE 5.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug is incompatible with the Zend Optimizer and Zend Studio Debugger extensions. These extensions should be commented out.

See: [NetBeans Wiki - How do I configure XDebug?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug)